# What should I do to make column 'A_up' stack on column 'B_down' column 'C_up' stack on column 'D_down'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A_up':np.array([200,316,440,560,664,765,859,944],dtype='int32'),
    'B_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
    'C_up':np.array([240,356,540,590,674,795,899,984],dtype='int32'),
    'D_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
},index=pd.Series(['10000','20000','30000','40000','50000','60000','70000','80000']))

df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

How can I do to make column 'A_up' stack on column 'B_down'     column 'C_up' stack on column 'D_down'？

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this, Kairen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A_up':np.array([200,316,440,560,664,765,859,944],dtype='int32'),
    'B_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
    'C_up':np.array([240,356,540,590,674,795,899,984],dtype='int32'),
    'D_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
},index=pd.Series(['10000','20000','30000','40000','50000','60000','70000','80000']))


N = df.shape[0]
ind = np.arange(N)
width = .3

p1 = plt.bar(ind-width/2,df['B_down'], color='red', width=width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind-width/2,df['A_up'], color='blue', width=width)

p3 = plt.bar(ind+width/2,df['D_down'], color='orange', width=width)
p4 = plt.bar(ind+width/2,df['C_up'], color='maroon', width=width)
plt.xticks(ind,df.index)
plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,p4], ['B_down','A_up','D_down','C_up'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or maybe this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A_up':np.array([200,316,440,560,664,765,859,944],dtype='int32'),
    'B_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
    'C_up':np.array([240,356,540,590,674,795,899,984],dtype='int32'),
    'D_down':np.array([258,443,590,713,822,921,1015,1100],dtype='int32'),
},index=pd.Series(['10000','20000','30000','40000','50000','60000','70000','80000']))
​
​
N = df.shape[0]
ind = np.arange(N)
width = .3
​
p1 = plt.bar(ind-width/2,df['B_down'], color='red', width=width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind-width/2,df['A_up'], color='blue', width=width, bottom=df['B_down'])
​
p3 = plt.bar(ind+width/2,df['D_down'], color='orange', width=width)
p4 = plt.bar(ind+width/2,df['C_up'], color='maroon', width=width, bottom=df['D_down'])
plt.xticks(ind,df.index)
plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,p4], ['B_down','A_up','D_down','C_up'])
​
plt.show()
```

[image]